# Energy needed to accelerate puck and change direction

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, acceleration

I am asking for an explanation for the example bellow:

How much energy is needed to accelerate a 0.113 kg hockey puck along an ice rink from 10 km/h south to 80 km/h north? Neglect frictional forces.

I would guess that we need energy to stop the puck and then accelerate it, so:

to stop: $W = \frac12mv_f^2 - \frac12mv_0^2 = -\frac12 \times 0.113 \times (\frac{10}{3.6})^2 = -0.44 
 \ J$

to accelerate: $W = \frac12mv_f^2 - \frac12mv_0^2 =\frac 12 \times 0.113 \times (\frac{80}{3.6})^2 = 27.9 \ J$

Now it seems rational to me to add up absolute values of those 2 energies which gives 28.34 J. But the correct answer should be 27.9 - 0.44 J = 27.46 J. For me, this doesn't make sense, because this answer requires less energy to stop it and accelerate it than just accelerate it. 
Hope this makes sense.
Thank you.

Comment: Sammy gerbil has explained the situation quite clearly. In addition to his explanations, note that you can get the answer via only one use of the work-energy theorem:
$$W_{tot}=\frac 12 mv_f^2 - \frac 12 mv_i^2=\frac 12 \times 0.113 \times (80^2 - (-10)^2) \times (\frac 1{3.6})^2 =27.46 \ J $$

Comment: I know that, but would the answer still be the same if we think of in terms of a hockey player, when a puck is coming to his stick and then he has to shoot it in opposite direction? I know that this is not in the example, just trying to get it properly.

Comment: Humans are not springs. They cannot store mechanical energy eg when going down stairs so that they can use it later when going back up. The hockey player would have to use energy to stop the puck. He would also have to use much more than 27.9J to accelerate a stationary puck, because he must move his body and accelerate his arms.

Answer (score 2):

The positive sign means that you give energy to the puck : work is done **on** the puck. The negative sign means that you take energy away from the puck : work is done **by** the puck.

The kinetic energy which is removed from the puck to stop it moving can be stored in a spring and used to make it move in the opposite direction with the same speed. So you only need to change its speed from 10kph to 80kph.

Or you could guide the puck around a smooth semi-circular track so that its direction of motion is reversed without altering its speed. The force on the puck from the track is always perpendicular to the motion of the puck so this force does no work and does not alter the speed of the puck.